# postgres libraries pgport and pgcommon in pg_config output

Tags: postgresql, pg-config

When I run pg_config, I can see -lpgcommon -lpgport under LIBS as below. But why I can't find any libraries related to them. Should I expect libpgcommon.so, libpgport.so or libpgcommon.a, libpgport.a under my postgres lib folder?

....
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lpthread -lselinux -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -lreadline -lrt -lcrypt -ldl -lm
VERSION = PostgreSQL 10.14
...